# С чем связано появление пунктов "Merge User Model" в контекстном меню проекта, и "Update Model on all projects" в меню решения Visual Studio 2013.

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

Есть решение, в котором два проекта. Веб-сервис и WinForms клиент для него. С непонятных мне причин, при правом клике на проект клиента, или на решение, стали появляться пункты меню "Merge User Model" и "Update Model on all projects" соответственно(раньше их не было). После появления этих пунктов меню VS, стала вести себя не совсем адекватно(указывает на ошибки в коде, которых на самом деле нет). 
Если выбрать пункт "Update Model on all projects" на решении, то VS что-то делает 10-20 сек. но в итоге проблему это не решает! Если выбрать пункт "Merge User Model" студия просит указать путь к файлу с "Model.User.xafml", который я нигде не могу найти.

Просьба, откликнуться, если кто-то стыкался с такой проблемой, или знает от куда ноги растут и в какую сторону копать!
Спасибо всем за раннее!

Comment: DevExpress установили?

Comment: Zufir да. Неужели опять в нём причина......

Comment: Ну, Merge user model - это его, если я не путаю.

Comment: Zufir А что с этим делать, не в курсе?

Comment: я бы попробовал для начала переустановить (ну, если он нужен, конечно). А какие ошибки выдает?

Comment: Zufir VS говорит что один из классов не помечен как сериализуемый, хотя раньше всё работало. Да и в коде ошибок не подсвечивает.